# Sending mail with ajax using php mailer

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email

I tried sending a mail with html tags and it worked fine. I do this when users try to get a new password when they have forgotten their own. I use recaptcha to prevent spam and it works all fine.

But when i recently made a contact form which sent the mail with jquery ajax, i get this message from hotmail:

"This message looks very suspicious to our SmartScreen filters, so we've blocked attachments, pictures, and links for your safety."

I get this message even if i just send plain text with `<br>` tags.

Any idea what the reason could be? I sent the same message using regular form with recaptcha and it worked. But sending it with ajax result in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to ask Microsoft.  [Their spam and bad-content filter](http://mail.live.com/mail/junkemail.aspx) can be quite aggressive.  You're probably also missing DKIM or SenderID/SPF on your domain.  [Jeff Atwood has a blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html) that is relevant.